# Adview disappears when aligned to bottom

Tags: android, admob, constraints

I want to display an AdMob banner underneath a web view in a fragment in Android Studio. 
With this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The AdMob banner is displayed at the top of the screen and the WebView won't show up at all. If I add this line to the AdView:

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

The AdView disappears and only the WebView shows up. What did I do wrong?

**Thank you for your help!**

Comment: Try removing: `android:layout_centerHorizontal` and then add `layout_alignParentBottom`.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work.

Comment: The simple and better solution would be using `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"  />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />



</RelativeLayout>
```